# Can a non-affine scheme admit an fpqc covering by an affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Suppose a scheme $X$ admits an fpqc covering $\operatorname{Spec} R \to X$. Is $X$ affine? I'd be particularly interested in 'nice' counterexamples (say when the covering is in fact fppf, or when $X$ is Noetherian).

Comment: No. Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$. Define $R$ to be the disjoint union of $D_+(x_0)$ and $D_+(x_1)$. Note that $D_+(x_0)$ and $D_+(x_1)$ are both abstractly isomorphic to the affine line, so that $R$ is given by Spec of $k[x_0/x_1] \times k[x_1/x_0]$ with $k$ the base field. Now, note that the natural morphism $R\to X$ is an etale covering (hence fpqc covering) of $X$. Since $X$ is not affine, we are done.

Comment: Ah, of course, in fact, all finite open coverings should do just fine it seems...

Comment: Yes. That's correct. You might be interested in the following statement (if I remember correctly):  given $f:X\to Y$ *finite* surjective (or maybe flat?) morphism of varieties, then $X$ is affine if and only if $Y$ is affine.

Comment: Wait, but $R \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is not finite then? I was already surprised that it was flat (since, intuitively, the number of pre-images 'jumps' on (1:0) and (0:1)). Gosh, I am so confused...

Comment: A morphism of varieties is *finite* if and only if it is quasi-finite and proper. The morphism $R\to \mathbb{P}^1$ is quasi-finite, but not proper. (It is etale hence flat.)

Comment: In fact, it might be good to think about why a proper fppf morphism $R\to X$ with $R$ affine is in fact finite.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar You just need finite. This is called 'Chevalley's Theorem' in Hartshorne. It's excercise III.4.2.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, I remember now. But just finite can't be enough. Need also surjective. Consider $R=$  Spec $k$ and $X = \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Sure, yeah, sorry, surjective was implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Ariyan Javanpeykar for clearing up my confusion. The answer to the main question is: a non-affine scheme can indeed be covered by a single affine scheme, and in fact, the standard covering of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x] \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} k[y]$ onto $\mathbb{P}^1$ will do.

When I thought about this question myself, I initially discarded these types of examples. I would not expect this morphism to be flat, because the sizes of the pre-images of this covering can 'jump' between 1 and 2, which contradicts the intuition that flat morphisms should have continuously varying fibres.

To clarify where this intuition goes wrong, let me simply remark that an open immersion is flat. Here, too, there is a 'jump' in the size of the fibres, but this 'jump' occurs, for the lack of better terms, on the boundary of an open set. And indeed a similar thing happens in the case of the aforementioned covering, as one can regard the images of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ and of $\operatorname{Spec} k[y]$ as being 'open' in $\mathbb{P}^1$.

An additional layer of confusion for me was that the covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$ seemed, to me, to be a finite morphism, but I was aware of the theorem saying that a scheme admitting a finite surjection from an affine scheme, is in fact affine (see Stacks Project, Tag 01ZT, or the exercise in Hartshorne's book as mentioned by Alex Youcis). My reasoning was that finite morphisms roughly correspond to having finite fibres, and this is clearly the case for our covering.

The intuition is flawed because, as Ariyan mentions, a morphism is finite if and only if it is quasi-finite (meaning of finite type and having finite fibres) and proper. It is the properness that fails for our covering. Using the intuition that proper schemes should be a 'compactness' criterion, one can predict why this indeed fails: viewing $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ and $\operatorname{Spec} k[y]$ as infinite lines, they clearly aren't compact, yet we're trying to map them onto a proper (compact) space $\mathbb{P}^1$. To be more mathematically precise, the morphism $\operatorname{Spec} k[x] \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} k[y] \to \mathbb{P}^1$ fails to be universally closed, as can be seen by taking the fibre product along the inclusion $D(x) \to \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Thanks for the Stacks tag. I didn't actually know a referencable source other than the exercise.